# Google StreetView in extjs 6

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I'm new to extjs and cant find a way to put a google StreetView inside a panel. Can someone point me in the right direction?. I have tried from interpreting an html inside a panel to the old GMapPanel but I doesn't work.

Currently I have this function where the panel shows up but doesn't show the street view

```
function () {
    alert("mostrar street view");

    new Ext.Panel({
        id: "streetView",
        xtype: "map",

        constrain: true,
        floating: true,
        resize: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        closable: true,

        style: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            //backgroundColor: '#000',
            border: "1px solid black",
        },


        listeners: {
            click: Ext.Window({
                layout: "fit",
                closeAction: "hide",
                title: "GPanorama Window",
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                x: 480,
                y: 60,
                items: {
                    xtype: "gmappanel",
                    gmapType: "panorama",
                    setCenter: {
                        lat: 42.345573,
                        long: -71.098326,
                    },
                },
            }),
        },

        draggable: {
            delegate: "div",
        },
    }).show();
```

I have also tried placing the property html as follows html:'CODE-BELOW'

```
    <head>
    <title>Street View split-map-panes</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map,
        #pano {
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
                const fenway = { lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326 };
                const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                    center: fenway,
                    zoom: 14,
                });
                const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
                    document.getElementById("pano"),
                    { position: fenway, pov: { heading: 34, pitch: 10 } }
                );
                map.setStreetView(panorama);
            }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="pano"></div>
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API-KEY&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly"
        async></script>
</body>
```

Comment: "can't make it work properly" is not an error description; that's alike "it doesn't work".

Comment: I'll edit that, I'm not a native English speaker

Comment: In order to answer it, i would need the gmappanel, but basically this should work: Add an afterRender listener, onAfterRender, get the ID of the cmp and use this id to render the Google Maps into it. You can furthermore load the scripts only there. 

Here (https://github.com/muzkat/ExtJS-Widgets/blob/master/src/components/muzkatMap/maps/osm.js) is an example with openStreetMaps, GMaps should basically similar. (Load and render the contents into a div)

Comment: I just solved this problem, If someone needs help with this, let me know!!